# Vanity Url in Joomla and jomsocial

Tags: regex, joomla

I know that jomsocial allows the following vanity urls to exist

domain.com/profile/jack

while this isnt strictly a vanity url the guys at jomsocial say it would be too intensive for performance to make this happen.

ok well could a clever regular expression convert at least

domain.com/jack to domain.com/profile/jack ? so that it works for every single profile that may get created, so it has to be clever and use variable 'username', in this case 'jack'

How do other frameworks address the routing for this is it modrewrite ? is it php etc....

thanks for any ideas or even the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with htaccess with something like this (untested)

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/profile/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The bigger issue I start to realise is that for every single menu item or real url I have like http://site.com/login I need to have an exception or my regex will think this could be a user called login

Answer (score 0):

SH404SEF has this built in as an option. You can edit the vanity URL to whatever you like. FOr me there was a performance overhead using SH404SEF. Seemed to slow my site down a lot. But worth a look.